# Saving Data of type (string, List<string>) in Viewstate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, viewstate

What collection to use to store Key, multiple values in ViewState. My data is of type `string Key`, `List<string> Values`, i.e.  a key can have one or more string values

Say I have countries and cities that I need to save in ViewState.

I will have

USA - NY, DC, Chicago

Canada - Toronto, Vancouver, Montreal

etc.

I'd like to save this data to ViewState and was wondering how best to save this without creating custom serializable objects etc. They're just strings.

Should I save them as string key, comma separated List Values?

Comment: `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`

Comment: Yes, I think this is the best way to go without having to create a custom object. Thanks... How do I mark it as an answer?

Comment: Posted an answer with an initialization example. You can mark, as accepted, only answers not comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this simple data could be stored in a `Dictionary<string, List<string>>`. The dictionary keys will be the State/Region and the values will be the cities list.

You can initialize it like this

```
Dictionary<string, List<string>> locations = new Dictionary<string, List<string>>
{
    { "USA", new List<string> {"NY", "DC", "Chicago"}},
    { "Canada", new List<string> {"Toronto", "Vancouver", "Montreal"}},
};
```

Then set the ViewState entry with that data

```
ViewState["locs"] = locations;
```

Answer (score 0):

You Could Use A Dictionary as mentioned in the comments, which would be the most efficient way when trying to access your data in that collection.You could also Use A Class Collection like so:

```
public class CollectingData
{
 public Collection<Countries> CollectCountries ;

 public CollectingData()
 {
 CollectCountries = new Collection<Countries>
 }
}

public class Countries
{
 public string country { get; set;}

 public List<string> states { get; set;}
}
```

And in the class you are trying to write to the collection in, for Every Country you Call a new Country of class with the Countries name as your string and then add your states or territories to your list. Then you can add that instance of the class to your collection. like so:

```
Countries mycountry = new Countries();
mycountry.states = new List<string>();

mycountry.country = "United States";
mycountry.states.Add("thisstate", "thatState");

CollectCountries.Add(mycountry);
```

You can do something similar to this for each country you want to add. Hopefully this helps you out. the Dictionary route will definitely be faster and easier than this however.